# ASPX Having trouble going to method update from gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm having trouble that when I press update in a gridview within my aspx page it is not going to the method.  This is part of my code:

Aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="FBGrid" runat="server"  
  AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"  
  OnRowEditing="FBGrid_EditRecord" OnRowCancelingEdit="FBGrid_RowCancelingEdit"  
  CellSpacing="10" OnRowUpdating="FBGrid_UpdateRecord"
  ShowFooter="True" 
  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  
  Height="159px" Width="695px">
```

And then within my aspx.cs the method is as follows:

```
protected void FBGrid_UpdateRecord(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int x = e.RowIndex;

    Label txtName = FBGrid.Rows[x].FindControl("BankName") as Label;
    Label txtRef = FBGrid.Rows[x].FindControl("NumberofReferencesRequired") as Label;
    Label txtItems = FBGrid.Rows[x].FindControl("MaximumNumberOfItems") as Label;
    Label txtID = FBGrid.Rows[x].FindControl("BankID") as Label;


    int a = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
    String b = txtName.Text;
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(txtItems.Text);
    int d = Convert.ToInt32(txtRef.Text);

    ForeignBankDetails FB = new ForeignBankDetails(a, b, c, d);
    BusinessLayerHandler.UpdateForeignBanks(FB);
    FillFBGrid();            
}
```

I have put a breakpoint and found that this method is being skipped completely.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator style="position: relative; left: -55px;" 
  id="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
  ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="ReferenceChoice" ValidationExpression="(^\d*\.?\d*[0-9]+\d*$)|(^[0-9]+\d*\.\d*$)">
    Invalid Numbers
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" id="RangeValidator3" controltovalidate="ReferenceChoice"
  type="Double" minimumvalue="0" maximumvalue="999999999999999" ForeColor="Red"
  errormessage="Invalid Range"/>
```

Comment: Is any validation stopping the call ?

Comment: No no validation is done within the grid view

Comment: But i do have validation to textboxes underneath tge grudview

Comment: Are those satisfied ? Does adding `CausesValidation="false"` to the textbox change anything ?

Comment: Yes the issue is with validation since i have 4 textboxed under the gridview which include validation is it possible that when i press update it ignores the validation since i added CausesValidation="false" in the gridview and still the same problem

Comment: For that you will have to add that part to the actual TextBox controls

Comment: I also tried inserting the causes validation false in the Textbox itself
asp:TextBox ID="ReferenceChoice" runat="server" Visible="False" CausesValidation="false" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: the validation is as follows 
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator  id="Requiredfieldvalidator3" runat="server" controltovalidate="ReferenceChoice" errormessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" />

Comment: <asp:RegularExpressionValidator style="position: relative; left: -55px;" id="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ForeColor="Red" 
                    ControlToValidate="ReferenceChoice" ValidationExpression="(^\d*\.?\d*[0-9]+\d*$)|(^[0-9]+\d*\.\d*$)">Invalid Numbers</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" id="RangeValidator3" controltovalidate="ReferenceChoice" type="Double" minimumvalue="0" maximumvalue="999999999999999" ForeColor="Red" errormessage="Invalid Range"/>

Comment: Please delete these comments and include the details in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the problem was that there was vlidation within the same page so the page was getting stuck